# How can I allow just one type of string pattern in a number pattern, while replacing the first 3 numbers to string - regex

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am writing a number pattern in MVC model. I need 2 types of patterns:

Either `12345-1234567-1`
OR `DDD45-1234567-1`

Where digits can be any digit 0-9. But only 3 D's can replace the starting of the pattern. DDD should be fixed.

Here is my code:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "NIC #")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[[D]{3}[0-9]{2}]|[[0-9]{5}]-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid NIC Number")]
public string NIC { get; set; }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Anubhav for the help. I tweaked my regex to meet my requirements.
Here is what I did.

```
@"^(DDD|\d\d\d)\d{2}-\d{7}-\d$"
```

- `(DDD|\d\d\d)` returned either exactly 3 D's or exactly 3 digits.
- `\d{2}` followed by exactly 2 digits.
- `-` matched a literal hyphen
- `\d{7}` matched the 7 digits
- `-` matched a literal hyphen
- `\d$` matched the last digit before line end.

The output generated was EITHER like `12345-1234567-1` OR like `DDD45-1234567-1`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use this regex:

```
@"^(?:D{3}|\d{3})\d{2}-\d{7}-\d$"
```

- `[D\d]{3}` will either match 3 `D`'s or 3 digits at start of input.
- `\d{2}` will match 2 digits
- `-` will match literal hyphen
- `\d{7}` will match 7 digits
- `-` will match literal hyphen
- `\d$` will match a single digit before line end.

Comment: Anubhava, thanks for the solution, but your code was accepting patterns like D2D2D45-1234567-1. So I tweaked it below.

Comment: For minor changes like this OP can leave comments and changing this wouldn't have taken more than few minutes for me. (See updated shorter regex).